# Phonegap keyboard cover input field

Tags: android, cordova

I am very new in Android apps development  and i'm encountering issue with keyboard covering my input fields and I did a search and came to know that I need to add in

> android:configChanges="screenSize|locale"

to the xml file. However I do not have the AndroidManifest.xml in my directory. All I have is config.xml which phonegap provided me.

Then I found this https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/160 but I have no idea where to put this

> android:windowSoftInputMode="value1|value2|valueN"

in my config.xml?

Any help is appreciated
Thanks in adavance

Comment: you need to set on AndoridMainfest.xml

Comment: Like I said, I don't have AndoridMainfest.xml thanks anyway

Comment: you have andorid project ?

Comment: No, I just plainly followed Phonegap installation and use phonegap run android in the commandline. All I have in the directory is config.xml

Comment: According to this https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/160 I can add in the config.xml. How do I do that?

Comment: see there project structure one AndoridMainfest.xml file

Comment: Sorry I really have no idea what you are talking about.  I don't have AndoridMainfest.xml

Comment: go to you project folder and see Projectname -> Platform -> android -> AndroidMainFest.xml

Comment: Projectname -> Platform is empty, should I create it the android folder manually?

Comment: Ooo Means you did not create the andorid project.  you need to create android project with command line ; phonegap local build android

Comment: Hi thanks alot Amit. I managed to installed the sdk, jdk, ant bla blah to the system environment and got the folder now. Thanks for leading me the way. really appreciate

Comment: One thing I would like to ask is, after changing the manifest.xml should I be using phonegap run android or phonegap build android?

Comment: with phonegap run android

Comment: I tried and it says " successfully installed onto device" and thats it. I can't find the apk file because I need to manually send it to my external android tab. Any idea how do I do this??

Answer (score 8):

Tried the accepted answer from @markj but it didn't work for me. What DID work was adding this to my config.xml:

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

You do get the "status bar" on top of your app but thats ok with me... Hope that helps

Comment: The combination of the above setting and the "android-windowSoftInputMode" did the trick for me

Comment: But what if we want to keep the fullscreen of the app?!

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the PhoneGap Build website and upload a zip file? And forget about the manifest file that Amit is talking about. I think he's just making everything more confusing. You need to understand the difference between a local development build and a PhoneGap online build. If you just want to test your app, you don't need to have the local development environment. You can zip your www folder and upload it to the PhoneGap Build service. No command line stuff and no complicated setup. If you want to edit soft keyboard settings, you can edit your config.xml and insert the following:

```
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateVisible|adjustResize" />
```

... or whatever options you want for the windowSoftInputMode.

The documentation is here:

https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml#platform

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Good luck with it.

Comment: This preference doesn't seem to exist anymore - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/9.x/config_ref/index.html#preference

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem using css media queries.

```
@media (max-height: 600px) {
  .login-header i {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

The keyboard resizes the screen and the css above consequently hides 'login-header' when the screen size falls below an arbitrary value (e.g. 600px). This allows the hidden input to come into view.

Comment: Hi, thanks for contributing to StackOverflow. The question you are answering is old and already answered - we'll be glad if you can give your effort to more pressing questions too.

Comment: The media-query is not triggered when the keyboard appears!

Answer (score 2):

With

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
```

I needed to do the following two

a. Use https://github.com/madebycm/AndroidBug5497Workaround/blob/master/AndroidBug5497Workaround.java to ensure that cordova / phonegap can see a change in window height

b. Add the code below to js. This step is required depending upon how the html is written

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady () {
    document.addEventListener('hidekeyboard', onKeyboardHide, false);
    document.addEventListener('showkeyboard', onKeyboardShow, false);
}

function onKeyboardHide() {
    console.log('onKeyboardHide');
}

function onKeyboardShow(e) {
  console.log('onKeyboardShow');
  setTimeout(function() {
    e.target.activeElement.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()
  }, 500) //needed timeout to wait for viewport to resize
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### You have the manifest file in plaforms/android Go ahead and add your option

`phonegap run android` will add an android build of your phonegap project to the platforms directory, read on http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

Comment: Hi I get "[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app" but I can't find the apk file anyway on my system. Because I am using an external Android tab to test on and it doesn't support USB, hence I need to send the apk file to my android tab manually.

Comment: Before I installed the SDK, when I run "phonegap run android", it will present me with a QR scan code, hence its easy to install to my Android device. But now when I run again after building with local SDK, there isn't any QR code to scan anymore lol. Please help :(

Comment: Basically you connect your device with your computer and run "phonegap run android". This will deploy the apk on the device automatically. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

Answer (score 0):

Your AndroidMainFest location : Projectname -> Platform -> android -> AndroidMainFest.xml
Your apk location : Project->bin->projectname.apk

set [android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" . . . >](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Answer (score 0):

Only one solution which worked for my full-screen app, it's to add to the Cordova application [ionic-plugin-keyboard](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard) plugin

```
cordova plugin add com.ionic.keyboard
```

JS code :

```
// This event fires when the keyboard will hide
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', keyboardShowHandler);

function keyboardShowHandler(e){
    $("body").addClass("keyboardOn");
}

// This event fires when the keyboard will show
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', keyboardHideHandler);

function keyboardHideHandler(e){
    $("body").removeClass("keyboardOn");
}
```

After that You could adjust the view with CSS.

ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25823491/634275

Comment: Can you post an example of "ajusting the view" with CSS?  I think your answer is promising, but it is incomplete.