# Show/hide soft keyboard for Cordova

Tags: cordova, keyboard, phonegap

Is it possible to show/hide the soft keyboard programmatically for Cordova/Phonegap?

Answer (score 4):

If the plugin is not working for you, maybe you can play with jquery .`focus()` and `.blur()` to show/hide the keyboard.

For example, the keyboard will show when an input is on `focus`, and to lose the focus you can call `blur`, and the keyboard will hide.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this plugin https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-keyboard

This plugin has two methods

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close
```

Comment: After I use the plugin, it shows the error -> Property "plugin" does not exist on type "cordova"   when I try to use that two methods.

Comment: No. I need to access Apache Cordova plugins by using Typescript

Comment: Actually I found this plugin https://github.com/amscomp/cordova-plugin-keyboard, but not able to use the method inside.

Comment: Useful link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477386/cordova-3-4-detect-keyboard-event

Answer (score 2):

The keyboard shows and hides itself based on input focus, in jQuery ...

```
// Show keyboard:
jQuery('#some-input-id').focus();

// hide keyboard:
jQuery('input, textarea').blur();
```

No plugin required.

Answer (score -1):

If you aren't using ionic, you may have luck with [this plugin](https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard). The Keyboard object is attached to the window, so the API is a little different.

```
window.Keyboard.show();
window.Keyboard.hide();
```

It's also worth noting that on iOS only the hide method works. There is no way to manually open the keyboard without having a focused input.

Comment: But it show Property 'Keyboard' does not exist on type 'Window' when I put this two function in index.ts

Comment: Have you installed the plugin and waited for the device ready event?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30740935/754604 may also help. `(<any>window).Keyboard`

Comment: I had installed the plugin and put the "window.Keyboard.hide();" into the function onDeviceReady()

Comment: I think you might want to try casting window then

Comment: May I know how to casting window?

Comment: Try `(<any>window).Keyboard` instead of `window.Keyboard` or another suggestion from that answer

Comment: I had try to put (<any>window).Keyboard.hide(); into the function onDeviceReady() and testing the result using Android emulator. But the soft keyboard still appear when I focus on the text input. The keyboard plugin Hide method should be works for iOS and Android right?

Comment: Yes it should work for both. It does not permanently hide the keyboard though. You will have to call it each time you want to hide the keyboard.

Comment: But now it still cannot function. Or maybe I put the (<any>window).Keyboard.hide() in the wrong place?

Comment: What do you mean by not functioning?

Comment: The soft keyboard still appear when I focus on text input using Android Emulator

Comment: Did you call the hide function after the input is focused?

Comment: May I know how to hide the soft keyboard for specific input? For example: I have a text input with id="user" at Login.html, then what should I do to use the <any>window.Keyboard.hide() in index.ts to hide the soft keyboard?

Comment: You should look into the focus event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus

Comment: Can I do it by this?
<input type="text" onfocus="Keyboard.hide();" value="">